# No shadows on transparent object ( Blender 2.8 )

Tags: shaders, transparency, lighting, shadows

**EDIT: I've found a  solution that works in my case, i've posted that solution below.**

**EDIT 2: Fixed "Eevee settings" to "Material settings in Eevee"**

So I've got a couple bushes in a scene and I noticed that they do not have any shadows on them, they cast shadows themselves but they don't catch shadows, I don't know if this is due to my node setup or some kind of inherent property of transparent textures, any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

I've included pictures of the issue, node setup and settings below.

Issue in Eevee:

[image: Issue in Eevee]

Issue in Cycles:

[image: Issue in Cycles]

Node Setup:

[image: Node Setup]

Material settings in Eevee:

[image: Eevee settings]

Comment: That doesn't look anything like the Properties/Scene settings for EEvee on mine.  I do recall seeing something about this in a YouTube video on 2.8/eeVee — what to enable to get the most out of transparancy and what still does not work.

Comment: Any  chance of new screenshots: one of nodes and another of result. With your consent, I wish to put screenshots of your works inside my scrapbook in link here. Credit is given. Scrapbook is for study purpose only. Approx 300 pages. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1ggss5H_XdWtIZ825iRuUjk7svvzdoPWM-cP1yv4kCCc/mobilepresent?slide=id.p

Comment: Hey, for sure, that scrapbook is a really neat idea, could be very useful. If you can please credit me as Somber as that's the name I go by most other places. Below are some imgur links to the node setup end result. GL with the scrapbook :) https://imgur.com/6XmxCfQ https://imgur.com/ncs2dhS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, turns out it was my node setup and isn't specific to transparency either.

The issue is that plugging the mix shader into a proper shader (Principled for example.) would cause my textures to display as purple, so instead I plugged directly from the mix shader into the material output, this is what causes the issue.

To avoid it you can simply plug the image texture into a separate shader and then plug that shader into the mix shader instead of directly from texture to mix shader.

Hopes this helps someone else, I struggled with it for a while.

[image: Fix]